# How to share folders via intent?

Tags: android

I have found this code for sharing image files via bluetooth/cloud storage/wifi. but how do i share the whole folder instead? here is my code-

```
private void shareImage() {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // If you want to share a png image only, you can do:
    // setType("image/png"); OR for jpeg: setType("image/jpeg");
    share.setType("image/*");

    // Make sure you put example png image named myImage.png in your
    // directory
    String imagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/myImage.png";

    File imageFileToShare = new File(imagePath);

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFileToShare);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image!"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here are some files.");
intent.setType("*/*"); /* allow any file type */

//Get all files in this particular location
File[] filesToSend = new File("/sdcard/myDocs").listFiles();

ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();
for (File file : filesToSend) {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    files.add(uri);
}

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` instead of `Intent.ACTION_SEND`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Here are some files.");
intent.setType("*/*"); /* allow any file type */

ArrayList<Uri> files = new ArrayList<Uri>();                    
for(String path : filesToSend /* List of the files you want to send */) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    files.add(uri);
}

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, files);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Updated answer. My answer is correct, please mark it as such.

Comment: i want to share this folder `sdcard/myDocs`

Comment: You could try something like `File[] filesToSend = new File("/sdcard/myDocs").listFiles();` ?

Comment: what should i replace that with?

Comment: i tried placing that after " File file = new File(path);" but i get so many errors

Comment: Just place it at the beginning. It won't work if you place it after it is referenced, especially not inside the loop. You'll also need to change the loop slightly to iterate over File objects instead of string objects. I've updated the code to reflect this, but I seriously recommend learning java before posting any more questions on this thread.

Comment: okay i pasted it in the very beginning, but i'm getting error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type File to String" on `filesToSend` in the line `for(String path : filesToSend /* List of the files you want to send */) {`

Comment: I've added a new answer to include the suggested line. I seriously recommend that you do some courses in java programming before posting any more questions on this thread. Please accept one of my answers as correct.

Comment: i accepted one, up voted both mate. one question, do i need ".listFiles();"?

Comment: your code is woking, i'm just wondering what does .listFiles(); do